# How to resolve VSCode import warnings with python scripts?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, warnings

VSCode gives a `warning` whenever I import a python file from the same directory, but in practice everything works fine when the scripts run.

In a sample directory:

```
root_folder
+-- __init__.py (empty)
+-- __main__.py (empty)
+-- __import.py (contains Parent class)
+-- toImport.py (contains Child(Parent) class)
```

I try the following in `toImport.py`:

```py
from __import import Parent

class Child(Parent): ...
```

Although I keep getting a `warning: unresolved import` even if it works. How can I resolve this issue or is it a VSCode issue?

Comment: Who is saying it's an unresolved import? Pylint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your projects `.vscode/settings.json` file.

```js
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./root_folder"]
}
```